# Can not open Visual Studio C# solution after upgrading from VS2010 to VS2013 (or VS2012), error message "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, projects-and-solutions

I had to upgrade a legacy project from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013.

When in VS 2013 I tried to load solutions, it showed migration report with warnings (and no errors!) - all warnings where `­Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in Visual Studio 2013, (..)`.

And in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, Output window I see this error message `The given path's format is not supported.` and as a result solution is not loaded.

I tried to find any information about `path's format` error message and it seems that it's about file names/directories, but I just can't find what has gone wrong with that during the solution loading/migration.

Any ideas what could be wrong/what should I check?

Comment: Could you update your post with the file path name for the solution? Please don't edit it because it's likely that something like a foldername is responsible.

Comment: You can check your `.sln` and `.csproj` files content and see if you notice something wrong. You can also compare the old `.sln` / `.csproj` files to see what has been changed

Comment: Did you try Clean Solution and build again?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs C:\ARBOR\AIRIS\AbWsClient1-\AbWsClient1.sln this "-" seems suspicious to me, but it's allowed in file names... so should this really have an impact?

Comment: @demonplus ... I couldn't load solution, so I guess it's not possible to `Clean Solution`?

Comment: @Prokurors If at all possible, try moving your solution to another folder without a dash and trying again. it *might* be possible that VS interprets the dash as a command modifier.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs well I copied to another folder without dash in it's name, but still result was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a project to create SQL CLR assembly, and as it turns out this project type (Visual C# SQL CLR Database Project) is no more available in Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

Save original version to some directory, then upgrade and compare directories with some comparison tool like kdiff3, etc and see what has changed

Comment: downvote was not from me - I have also witnessed quite some unmotivated downvotes recently. So upvote from me to compensate

Comment: Any luck with upgrading solution?

Comment: Turned out I could avoid upgrading it, but turns out problem cause was that the project template is not present in VS2012 and VS2013